# Scopes with Rails and Mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have this 3 dependent models with **Mongoid**:

```
 class Account
   has_many :apps
 end

 class App
   belongs_to :account
   has_many :devices
 end

 class Device
   belongs_to :app
 end
```

I would like to **get all the Device elements that belongs_to an Account**, but the relation between **Device** and **Account** is through the model **App**.

In an **ActiveRecord** environment, it would be something like this:

```
scope :for_account, ->(account) { joins(:app).where("app.account = ?", account) }
```

**How can I do this with Mongoid?**

Comment: What do you think it is the best option? To include a "belongs_to :account" in the Device class or to introduce a something like "alize :app, :account_id"?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways that I can think of to solve this.

Mongoid relations provide us with a pretty hefty set of methods to help us access objects.

For example:

```
app.account       #returns account object
app.account_id    #returns bson id of account object
account.apps      #returns collection of apps
account.app_ids   #returns array of app bson ids
```

We can use this so find all devices who's app ids are included in the list of app ids for an account.  Something like:

```
Device.where(app_id: { '$in' => account.app_ids})
```

This will return a nice collection, just like any other mongo query, but has the drawback of searching the entire Device collection.  Depending on your db size this might be a performance hit that you're not comfortable with.

Alternatively:

```
account.apps.collect{ |a| a.devices}.flatten
```

will provide an *array* of device items collected from all of the apps in an account.

This has the advantage of a more efficient search, and it is likely that the array will work fine for whatever you need this collection for.

Hope this helps!